# stop colorbox popup closing when clicking anywhere outside the popup

Tags: colorbox

We have a colorbox modal popup which we don't want to close unless the user clicks the "X" at the top right of the popup. Currently, it is closing if you click anywhere outside the popup area.

Many thanks!
Paul

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Colorbox has options to modify that functionality. Just add this to your colorbox instantiation:

```
$("#selector").colorbox({
    //your other colorbox options
    //...
    escKey: false,
    overlayClose: false
});
```